# Year is displaying as 2,014.00. It is in a formula. Cannot right click format number. How to make it 4 digits

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that is pulling average results per quarter.  This will be a growing, rolling report with up to 5 years of data on the graph.  I need to output Q1-2014, etc. I have created the quarters

```
if month ({ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE}) in [1,2,3] then "Q1"
Else if month ({ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE}) in [4, 5, 6] then "Q2"
Else if month ({ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE}) in [7, 8, 9] then "Q3"
Else if month ({ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE}) in [10, 11, 12] then "Q4"
```

And created a formula to append the year to each quarter:

```
{@Quarterly} & " - " & year({ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE})
```

The result looks like this:  Q1-2,014.00.

How do I get it to look like Q1-2014?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What language is this? "decimal" doesn't give us much to go on. We have no information other than what you tell us; we can't see your screen or read your thoughts from where we are, so you have to be specific with your question.

Comment: this is just crystal syntax.  I was hard pressed to find the correct required tag.  Does this help?  I am new to this type of forum.

Comment: @user3183579 you can always go ahead and edit your original question and its tags. If I got you right, a fitting tag would be `crystal-reports` - not sure though as I got no experience with that stuff :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  that should make it easier to find help!

Comment: @user3183579: For future reference, when you're entering tags you can just start typing one (for instance, "crystal"), and a small window with possible matches appears with a list of possible matches. It would have found the `crystal-reports` tag for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the formula like this.

```
{@Quarterly} & " - " & ToText(year({ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE}),0,"")
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this and the formula checked out fine before I saved it.  Once I saved it, it returned the following message: "Bad number format string".  any idea what that means?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Q" + ToText(DatePart("q",{ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE})),"#") + "-" + ToText(DatePart("yyyy",{ORDER_RESULTS.RESULT_DATE})),"#")
```